# RANSAC implemetation?

Tags: laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to implement RANSAC algorithm for robust detection of lines and corridors using a Hukoyo 2D laser so if someone can help me i would be grateful.I'm trying to find codes wich include ROS cpp implementation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209374/ransac-implemetation?/) by [ANY](https://answers.ros.org/users/22379/any/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its implemented as part of PCL (http://wiki.ros.org/pcl) . See this tutorial: [pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/random_sample_consensus.php#random-sample-consensus](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/random_sample_consensus.php#random-sample-consensus)

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0